# getContentResolver undefined in SMS inbox_sent access

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins

I am using PhoneGap 2 and tried to add SMS functionality with
[inbox_sent](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMS%20inbox_sent%20access). Following instruction I added SMSRead.java file.

But I have undefined error for

```
   private ContentResolver getContentResolver(){
       return this.ctx.getContentResolver();
    }
```

saying that

> The method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type
> LegacyContext

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the article at http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/phonegap-android-plugins-sometimes-we.html to be helpful.

There have been some changes to the API for this plugin and the code needs to be updated.

As per the information on the page above, you should update your method to read.

```
private ContentResolver getContentResolver(){
    return cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver();
}
```

I am still in the process of integrating this plugin into my project and I know there are challenges beyond this point (but the Java code compiles now at least.)